# Warning/hasrah nowadays

Tags: halacha, sanhedrin, hasraah-warning

If 2 witnesses give a warning to someone not to transgress an aveira, I.e. “don’t eat that dead animal or you will get lashes,” and the man eats it anyway. If the Bais Hamikdash and Sanhedrin are established the day after, if the witnesses come to bais din, would the transgressor receive lashes for his sin?

Comment: Why might he not that you think to ask?

Comment: I would assume the question is based on the גמרא in סנהדרין  that says on 41a that התראה is for the concept that for there to be a punishment the transgressor needs to be התיר עצמו למיתה, he needs to acknowledge the punishment. With this concept, I understand the question to be, is it possible to acknowledge that this action will be punished, if currently the punishment is unenforceable without the sanhedrin.

Comment: IIRC when the Samhedrin moved out of the Lishkas Hagazis before the Churban, they were allowed, and possibly did, return to judge specific cases. Now, how could the eidim of given hasrah if everyone knew they weren’t sitting in the lishka? It would seem that this isn’t an issue as long as the transgressor understood the repercussions possibilities. A potential difference is that at least then there was a functioning Sanhedrin so people understood the possibility. Regardless, this is a question that’s hilchisa lmishicha? When it happens, Sanhedrin will pasken what to do